# How to create correct .vcf file based on data.frame in R? Subscript is out of bounds?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, vcf-variant-call-format

currently I'm working with `signeR` package which allows you to create signatures of somatic mutations. First of all I'd like to reproduce their result from [vignette](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/signeR/inst/doc/signeR-vignette.html).

As you see there are two options of input data `.vcf` file and previously preprocessed  `mutation counts file` which is simple data frame obtained by their `genCountMatrixFromVcf()` function ..in fact from `.vcf...`

Of course [here](https://github.com/rvalieris/signeR/tree/master/inst/extdata) you can find some example `.vcf` file and this mutation count matrix ready for further analysis.

In vignette they used (as I read) [this](ftp://ftp.sanger.ac.uk/pub/cancer/Nik-ZainalEtAl/) data: **SUBSTITUTIONS_13Apr2012_snz.txt**.
So I decided to create a `.vcf` file from this data frame and go through all steps of the vignette.

So I made a several simple steps to build `.vcf` from mentioned above data:

```
dat <- read.table('SUBSTITUTIONS_13Apr2012_snz.txt', header = T, sep = '\t')
t <- dat[,c(3,4,6,7)]
t$chr <- paste("chr", t$chr, sep="")
colnames(t) <- c('chr','pos1','ref','alt')
t$ID <- rep('.',nrow(t)) 
t$QUAL <- rep('.',nrow(t))
t$FILTER <- rep('.',nrow(t))         
t$INFO <- rep('.',nrow(t))
t$FORMAT <- rep('.',nrow(t))
t$Sample <- rep('.',nrow(t))
t <- t[, c('chr', 'pos1', 'ID', 'ref', 'alt', 'QUAL',   'FILTER',   'INFO')]
colnames(t) <- c('#CHROM',  'POS',  'ID',   'REF',  'ALT',  'QUAL', 'FILTER',   'INFO')
```

As a result we have:

```
> head(t)
  #CHROM     POS ID REF ALT QUAL FILTER INFO
1   chr1  809687  .   G   C    .      .    .
2   chr1  819245  .   G   T    .      .    .
3   chr1 1911011  .   C   G    .      .    .
4   chr1 2112413  .   T   C    .      .    .
5   chr1 2927666  .   A   G    .      .    .
6   chr1 3359791  .   C   T    .      .    .
```

All mandatory columns for `.vcf` file are present. I made this type of files previously, than I used `readVcfAsVRanges()` everything worked fine.

However here in `signeR` package there's some problem...
Because if I wont to create this **mutation count matrix** I have an error:

```
vcfobj <- readVcf("21_breast.vcf", "hg19")
mut <- genCountMatrixFromVcf(BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19, vcfobj)
Error in normalizeDoubleBracketSubscript(i, x, exact = exact, error.if.nomatch = FALSE) : 
  subscript is out of bounds
```

So I tried to find out what is wrong with my `.vcf` file in comparison to 'working' ones...

My file:

```
vcfobj
class: CollapsedVCF 
dim: 183916 0 
rowRanges(vcf):
  GRanges with 5 metadata columns: paramRangeID, REF, ALT, QUAL, FILTER
info(vcf):
  DataFrame with 0 columns: 
geno(vcf):
  SimpleList of length 0:
```

Thier 'working' example file (in fact after run `genCountMatrixFromVcf()` function there's also error but different... Not important at this moment).

```
example <- readVcf("example.vcf", "hg19")
example
class: CollapsedVCF 
dim: 44 7 
rowRanges(vcf):
  GRanges with 5 metadata columns: paramRangeID, REF, ALT, QUAL, FILTER
info(vcf):
  DataFrame with 1 column: INFO
  Fields with no header: INFO 
geno(vcf):
  SimpleList of length 5: GT, AD, DP, GQ, PL
geno(header(vcf)):
      Number Type    Description                                                                           
   GT 1      String  Genotype                                                                              
   AD .      Integer Allelic depths for the ref and alt alleles in the order listed                        
   DP 1      Integer Approximate read depth (reads with MQ=255 or with bad mates are filtered)             
   GQ 1      Integer Genotype Quality                                                                      
   PL G      Integer Normalized, Phred-scaled likelihoods for genotypes as defined in the VCF specification
```

As you se the `dim` va.lues are different I have `0` there, so it might be the problem. So I'd like to ask you how to fix my `.vcf` file?

Comment: From the vignette, is not does appear that you need to create a VCF file from this tabular data. A VCF file is a valid input to the program (section 3.1 in vignette), but you can also input a table instead (section 3.2 in vignette). So, why do you require the conversion of the table/data.frame to VCF?

Comment: Yes but this table is 'mutation count table' which is made from vcf file by genCountMatrixFromVcf() function